# Ionic/Angular update array from Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to this..

I have a controller

```
.controller('AudioCtrl', function($scope, Audio, AudioSockets) {

$scope.audioSockets = AudioSockets.list;

$scope.$watch(function() {return AudioSockets.list}, function () {
  $scope.audioSockets = AudioSockets.list;
  console.log(AudioSockets.list);
});
```

That references a service

```
.service('AudioSockets', function() {

// public API
this.list = sockets;
});
```

Where I'm trying to use a Javascript array that get's updated via external code

```
var sockets = [];
```

How do I get the value of what's in those sockets into my Controller?

Answer (score 0):

Add third parameter `boolean true` to make deep watch

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
  return AudioSockets.list
},
function(oldVal,newVal){
  console.log(newVal);
},true);
```